# Why R isn't replacing the function argument by the given value?

Tags: r, function

I wrote this simple function to install and import libraries, if they are not installed yet. Here is my code:

```
check_library <- function(my_lib){
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      library(my_lib)
    },
    error = {
      install.packages(my_lib)
      library(my_lib)
    }
  )
}

lista_libraries = list('tidyverse', 'rvest', 'bizdays','dplyr','lubridate')

for (k in lista_libraries) {
  check_library(k)
}
```

However, when I run the function (within the above loop) `R` prints the following `Error message`:

```
Error in library(my_lib) : there is no package called ‘my_lib’
```

I mean, `my_lib` is just the argument name, why R is trying to evaluate it instead of evaluating the actual value used when the function is called?

Comment: see the `character.only` argument to `library()`.

Comment: thank you. It solves my problem!

Comment: Normally `require` would be used do do this, not `library`.In that case you don't need `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that my_lib is going to be a character string you can specify `library(my_lib, character.only = TRUE)`. However, if you want to be able to use both quoted and unquoted library names like `check_library(dplyr)` then you can do something like this:

```r
check_library <- function(my_lib)
{
  package <- as.character(substitute(my_lib))

  if (!(package %in% installed.packages()))
  {
    install.packages(package)
  }

  if (package %in% installed.packages())
  {
    library(package, character.only = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Error message: `Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘x’`.

Comment: @Hartnäcking I have edited the answer. If you run this in the console and then type `check_library(dplyr)` dies it still say the same thing?

Comment: Don’t gratuitously use `parse`. And there’s no reason to use it here, it only leads to overly complex, inefficient, unsafe and brittle code. You can use `bquote`, `substitute` or `as.call` instead. But even those aren’t necessary here since you can simply pass `character.only` to `library`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph good points. It was just a toy example to show that one can use non-standard evaluation, as R users are used to doing with library names. I have updated the answer. I know you may still think this is inefficient or overly complex, but it's still far simpler than require().

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with a tryCatch expression, you can get the same effect from the require function, which loads the package if it exists, otherwise it returns FALSE

```
check_library <- function(x){
   x <- as.character(substitute(x)) #will make sure x is converted to a string if it isn't already
   if(!require(x, character.only = T)){
       install.packages(x)
   }
}
```